# Xcode + CocosBuilder: Could not create class of type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I use Xcode 4.5 + CocosBuilder-3.0 alpha + cocos2d from cocosBuilder's source:

```
cocos2d: cocos2d-iphone v2.1-rc0
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: 6.0 (0x06000000)
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: NO
```

I try to connect my MainMenuScene. I created a new project on cocosbuilder, added a new file subclass of CClayer, and set CClayer CustomClass as 'MainMenuScene'. Then I published and copy MainMenuScene.cb, MainMenuScene.ccb, my and Builder's images to my Xcode project and added it in my project + set my project as target membership.

[image]

Then I added following line to my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CCScene* myScene = [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"MainMenuScene.ccbi"];
}
```

But in this string I see **CCBReader: Could not create class of type MainMenuScene**
Why??? Help me please. I found one post [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/111740), but I do not understand how to use it in my project.

Comment: being an alpha build it is very likely that it might be a bug, you should ask this on the cb forum too

Comment: "and set CClayer CustomClass as 'MainMenuScene'." I think that's your problem, CCBReader is looking for a class called MainMenuScene to load, but you don't have one because you are using a .ccbi file instead.  Try deleting the 'MainMenuScene' from the custom class field.